# SQLFilter search method within today and yesterday

Tags: sql, shopware

I am running Shopware 6 using an API connection to my ERP system.
But in order to keep the number of requests low, I need to set it up between today and yesterday.

I have searched everywhere, but is there a way to do this on this line?

```
sqlfilters=(**t.tms%3Alike%3A'%252023-07-18%25'**)&pagination_data=true
```

Hope someone is able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is ...`t.tms BETWEEN "2023-07-17 00:00:00" AND "2023-07-18 23:59:59"`

Comment: That is correct, but without the need of changing the dates. so something like date of SQL server = 20-07-2023 +  the day before.

Comment: if you're using current date 
`t.tms BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), " 00:00:00") AND CONCAT(CURDATE()," 23:59:59")`
if it's a specified date then try this
`DATE_SUB(CAST("2023-07-20" AS DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: I tried as you said, but its not working, is there another way ?  sqlfilters=(**t.tms%3Alike%3A'%252023-07-18%25'**)&pagination_data=true  is what is filled in to retrieve the data from an api request.